# How to find x values from y value using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a plotting from 2 numpy arrays named xPos (x Value) and xProfile (y Value). It is show in the attached image.

[image: plot]

Here is my code to plot values:

```
xProfile = 100*(eDepMat[:,41,41]/eDepMat[41,41,41])
xPos = np.linspace(-20, 20, 81)
plot4 = ax4.plot(xPos, xProfile)
ax4.set_xlabel('x positions [cm]')
ax4.set_ylabel('Relative dose [%]')
ax4.grid(color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.1)
ax4.set_title('X Profile')

# xProfile=[1.65357
1.44279
1.99039
2.11737
2.41571
2.20419
2.64493
2.90684
3.90013
4.3398
5.64764
7.28404
9.31809
10.6319
12.9572
19.3046
24.318
28.3353
35.8915
43.3915
53.1689
59.4102
69.7083
81.97
85.2627
89.1488
95.4716
96.9098
98.7664
98.7688
98.1199
97.5785
99.2019
97.9184
101.332
99.6836
98.8609
99.778
101.83
98.1091
101.7
100
102.626
102.36
99.5246
104.03
104.136
106.218
106.162
103.319
105.376
104.213
103.848
102.196
103.402
99.6002
91.5528
85.2763
77.0413
63.0445
53.9208
44.4396
34.8563
29.3416
22.0063
17.2319
12.4915
10.3133
7.72007
5.79157
4.3541
3.97394
2.9509
2.72589
2.71177
2.61017
2.00052
1.96052
1.66793
1.36369
1.91262
]
```

I would like to find x Value from y Value = 50 using Python.
I tried to use np.interp(), but is was incorrect. The result must be ~+10.45 or ~-10.45

```
np.interp(50, xPos, xProfile)
Out[60]: 6.488597663333305

np.interp(50, xProfile, xPos)
Out[61]: 20.0
```

Can anyone help me please. Thank you in advance.

I need a bit of code for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *simple/naïve* way to do it :

```
y_val = 50 # <-- change here the y-value

l_idx = np.abs(xProfile - y_val).argmin()
r_idx = np.abs(np.flip(xProfile) - y_val).argmin()

x1_val = xPos[l_idx] # -10.0
x2_val = xPos[r_idx] # +10.0

ax4.plot(x1_val, y_val, 'ro', label='y=50')
ax4.plot(x2_val, y_val, 'ro', label='y=50')

ax4.axhline(y=y_val, color='gray', linestyle='--')

ax4.axvline(x=x1_val, ymin=0, ymax=y_val/100, color='gray', linestyle='--')
ax4.axvline(x=x2_val, ymin=0, ymax=y_val/100, color='gray', linestyle='--')

plt.show();
```

[image]

Comment: You assume in this solution that there are exactly two solutions

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that you can linearly interpolate the data between two points.

```
y_target = 50
b = np.sign(xProfile - y_target)
b = (b[:-1]*b[1:] < 0) # negative where y_target between two elements
b = np.where(b)
x_vals = []
for idx in b:
  # use linear interpolation
  fac = (y_target-xProfile[idx])/(xProfile[idx+1]-xProfile[idx])
  x_vals.append( (1-fac)*xPos[idx]+fac*xPos[idx+1] )
print(x_vals)

# [array([-10.16205228,  10.20676708])]
```